# Free software webmail server that can send "you have new mail" notifications

Tags: open-source, web-apps, email, server, notification

We want to provide a webmail to our members. But since members are likely not to check this webmail very often (some of them have a life) we want the system to send notifications to the members about unread mail every day.

Are there any free software webmail servers that support sending notifications to other platforms?

Notification platforms include: Signal Private Messenger, email (to their primary email address), SMS, Matrix, IRC, Wire, Facebook Messenger, Direct message for Twitter/Instagram/Snapchat.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than install additional software, just configure the users' clients to pop up a notification when you send a message. For example, on Thunderbird, the add-on [FilterQuilla](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/reviews/) can be configured to run a script or to start a program when email from a specific source arrives.

Comment: How do you configure Signal Private Messenger, SMS, Matrix, IRC, Wire, Facebook Messenger, Direct message for Twitter/Instagram/Snapchat to do that? We cannot force our members to install given software. We have to support the systems they have.